# iOS UIImageView dataWithContentsOfURL returning empty

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, uiimageview

I'm trying to display an image from a URL in a UIImageView and I'm seeing some very peculiar results. The bit of code that I'm testing with is below

```
imageURL = @"http://images.shopow.co.uk/image/user_dyn/1073/32/32";
imageURL = @"http://images.shopow.co.uk/assets/profile_images/default/32_32/avatar-male-01.jpg";

NSURL *imageURLRes = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURLRes];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

NSLog(@"Image Data: %@", imageData);
```

In it's current form I can see data in the output window which is what I'd expect. However if comment out the second imageURL so I'm referencing the first I'm getting empty data and therefore nil is being returned by imageWithData. What is possibly more confusing is that the first image is basically the same as the second but it's been through a PHP processing script. I'm nearly certain that it isn't the script that's causing the issue because if I use this instead

```
imageURL = @"http://images.shopow.co.uk/image/product_dynimg/389620/32/32"
```

the image is displayed and this uses the same image processing script. I'm struggling to find any difference in the images that would cause this to occur. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about if you add the extension to the URL (i.e. http://images.shopow.co.uk/image/user_dyn/633/32/32.png)

Comment: And try looking at if it's the `URLWithString` that's returning `nil`?

Comment: It looks like the direct URL does not use Gzip where as the other one does. You might want to look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) because they seem to handle GZip.

Comment: first u can check on the pc browser, does this url has an image..? And then implement

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses.
Adding the extension doesn't do anything, the URLWithString returns the URL as expected and I can open the image(s) in a web browser. I'll look into AFNetworking regarding the GZip.

Comment: To rule out the possibility that GZip is causing the issue, if I add the extension to the end of the problematic URL (http://images.shopow.co.uk/image/user_dyn/1073/32/32) GZip is no longer used however the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something with the server configuration.

```
$ curl -v http://images.shopow.co.uk/assets/profile_images/default/32_32/avatar-male-01.jpg
```

returns non-zero `Content-Length` and the actual image bits. And when I do:

```
$ curl -v http://images.shopow.co.uk/image/user_dyn/633/32/32
```

I get the following headers and zero-length response:

```
> GET http://images.shopow.co.uk/image/user_dyn/633/32/32 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: images.shopow.co.uk
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 18 Oct 2012 10:51:31 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.15
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
< Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Surprisingly in the browser both links work and return an image.

**Update:** I figured it out. It's the user agent.  Try it like this:

```
$ curl -v \
    -A "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4" \
    http://images.shopow.co.uk/image/user_dyn/633/32/32
```

and you get your image bits.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out to be a configuration setting for the application serving the images. It was dependant on where the request was coming from and your suggestion of user agent got me on the right track.